# is anvir task manager using your WiFi

Tags: security

Anvir task manager used to have a free and pro version. I have used the pro version for quite some time and needed to reinstall on a new PC, but see on their site: https://www.anvir.com that there is only one version now with all the features and it is free.

I was curious as to why they made it free and clicking on the [FAQ](https://www.anvir.com/faq.htm) link  I see this:

> Your use of AnVir Task Manager is free of charge in exchange for safely using some of your device's resources (WiFi and very limited cellular data), and only when you are not using your device. You may turn this off from the settings menu. Please see our TOS for further information.

The [TOS](https://www.anvir.com/tos.txt) says this

> In return for some of the premium features of AnVir Software, you may choose to be a peer on the Luminati network. By doing so you agree to have read and accepted the terms of service of the Luminati SDK SLA (http://luminati.io/legal/sdk-sla). You may opt out of the network from settings.

I can't find any "setting" in anvir that gives an option to turn this use of your resources on or off

Does anyone know what resources anvir is actually using and if there is a way to turn it off?

Comment: Have you asked anvir?

Comment: Thanks,  that is the best thing to do. Just wanted to get the question up in case others had the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as suggested I emailed Anvir and the reponse was:

> Currently this is not used

No idea if / when it will be used and whether we get any warning